# Tkinter OpenCV Python - Fail to allocate memory after 2h

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have created a simple video game BOT using openCV 4.6.0 and 64-bit python.
Program flow listed below;

```
1. Open GUI using tkinker 
2. Upon pressing start a new process opens in a loop (main loop)
3. Program takes a screenshot of my screen (850x650 pixels) and saves as PNG
4. Load in the screenshot to openCV MAT and start image processing with cv.matchtemplate
5. Repeat main loop. After 1 hour kill this process, open a new process and repeat
```

The reason why I have this running on a separate process was because I thought that maybe openCV was locking memory in the background so I'm essentially doing a "Reboot".

All the OpenCV related code is below;

```
 #Static Images
 hp_img = cv.imread(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + 'hp.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 worldmap_img = cv.imread(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + 'worldmap.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 settings_menu = cv.imread(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + 'settings.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 black_screen = cv.imread(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + 'blackscreen.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def checkBlackScreen():
global threshold

screenShot = pyautogui.screenshot(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + "screen.png", region=(0, 0, 850, 650))

screen_img = cv.imread(LOCAL_DIRECTORY + 'screen.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv.matchTemplate(screen_img, black_screen, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
_, max_val, _, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)

del result
del screen_img
del screenShot
gc.collect()

if (max_val > threshold):
    print("[BAD] Stuck in black screen")
    return True
else:
    print("[Good] Not stuck in black screen : ", max_val)
    return False
```

The main loop just calls the function above and presses buttons accordingly. Most of the program provided below;

```
#Main entry of the program    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    GUI()  

#GUI using TK
def GUI():

    root = Tk()
    frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
    frm.grid()
    ttk.Label(frm, text="Hello World!").grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=1, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm, text="Start", command=startBotProcess).grid(column =2, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm, text="Stop", command=stopBot).grid(column =3, row=0)
    ttk.Button(frm, text="Set WorldMap XY", command=StartListenClick).grid(column =4, row=0)
    #ttk.Button(frm, text="Set WorldMap XY", command=checkEXPMap).grid(column =4, row=0)
    root.mainloop()

#Set world map X,Y    
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    listen_for_mouse = False
    if pressed:
        global MOUSE_X
        global MOUSE_Y
        
        MOUSE_X = x
        MOUSE_Y = y
    
        print('World Map set to : ',(MOUSE_X, MOUSE_Y))
        listen_for_mouse = False
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False    

# Collect events until released    
def StartListenClick():
    listen_for_mouse = True
    with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        if (listen_for_mouse == True):
            listener.join()  

#Start new BOT Process
def startBotProcess():
    
    print("[SYSTEM] New BOT Process STARTED")
    
    time_start = time.time()
    
    ps = Process(target=processMain, args=(MOUSE_X,MOUSE_Y))
    ps.start()
    ps.join()
    
    stopBot()
    print("[SYSTEM] Bot Process CLOSED")
    
    if (time.time() - time_start > SLEEP):
        print("[SYSTEM] Restart Timer Created")
        t = Timer(SLEEP_TIME, botSleep)        
        t.start()

def processMain(x,y):

    global MOUSE_X, MOUSE_Y
    MOUSE_X = x
    MOUSE_Y = y
    
    startBot()

def startBot():

print("[SYSTEM] STARTING BOT - Click Window")

global running
global GAME_STATE
global CUT_SCENE    
global CHAT_FOUND
global TRANSITION_TIME

printData()

time.sleep(2)
running = True
start_time = time.time()

while (running == True):
    if (GAME_STATE == 0):   #First, lets see if we are in a map
        if (checkMap() == True):
            GAME_STATE = 1
        else:
            print("GAME_STATE is 0 - Cannot determine if player is on a map")
            debugger()
```

Now eventually after ~ 2hours of running the python command prompt will show a fail to allocate memory error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeRcq.png)

The line that its referring too is the cv.matchtemplate.
Task manager shows the program only using 50mb of memory. Total memory usage on my computer is 51%

Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this? Task manag

Updated screenshot with task manager and failed allocation;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7I1T.png)

Comment: Post snippet code in line 215.

Comment: @toyotaSupra line 215 refers to result = cv.matchTemplate in checkblackscreen

Comment: please present a [mre]. this is required. your current question here is not debuggable. -- I'm betting it's something to do with tkinter, or pyautogui. OpenCV hasn't leaked any memory in all the times I've used it. it only fails here because you are out of memory in general, and OpenCV dares to try such a "large" allocation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz My apologies. I have updated the main post with most of the code from the program. Mouse X,Y is used to store where the game window is. The only functions that are not provided simply click the window using pyautogui.click or pydirectinput.press. If you require any clarification or something I missed please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `startBotProcess` is an event handler, yet you block in there (`ps.join()`), nearly forever, for the thread to end. that will lock up the entire gui. -- have you looked at a process monitor and checked the memory consumption of the python process? or any other process?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I removed all code related to the tkinter and just started a new process right when the program launch. It seems that I am still running into the same error with allocation of memory. I was watching the process open and close and it would take up 25mb. My system has 16gb available. I even went as far as to implement the same logic in Java (non-heap related) but I am receiving allocation errors after running for so much time.

Comment: 25 MB *once* is nothing. "leak" means it would have to _keep growing_, significantly. I doubt it's doing that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hi Chris, I agree with you in that it does not appear to be a "leak" per say. However, as you can see from the updated screenshot it feels like my system is 'Locking/Not freeing' memory. As you can see even after rebooting the program it still fails to allocate. I suspect it could be the game doing the repeated action specified by my program... although I'm not sure if what I described is possible or how i would check.

Comment: ok... it says there, memory utilization 56%, with the top couple of processes accounting for ~2.5 GB. does your system have about 4 GB of RAM? what memory consumption does the python process have before it crashes? can you reproduce this OOM error while the game doesn't run?

Comment: Hi Christoph my system has 16gb of memory. The python process has a total of 50mb before it crashes. That is a good idea to test my script without the game running to see if the  OOM error is reproduced. If the error is not reproduced then I think my suspicion is right in that the game is locking memory. Thanks for the suggestions I will conduct some more test.